# Decreasing Polyline Stroke Width

Tags: svg, polyline

I am trying to mimic the behavior of markers on white boards and was wondering if it I can do it with svg polylines. I know the stroke width can be set but can be it changed to vary depending on the velocity of the mouse which I can figure out or is it just a constant value for the stroke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple stroke widths in a single polyline element. I think canvas is probably a better fit for this task.

Comment: Will look into canvas, hopefully it supports it

Answer (score 3):

Or if you wanted to use SVG, instead of using a `<polyline>`, use a series of connected `<line>`s