# Path with ascending stroke width

Tags: canvas, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make a path with an ascending stroke-width attribute in a force-layout. If the target value is higher than the source value the link should be wider in the target side.

The only example that I could find is this =>http://jsfiddle.net/bfzsaL3m/2/

I also came across this question [Decreasing Polyline Stroke Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003323/decreasing-polyline-stroke-width). It says this can't be done but it's a bit old.

Right now my code uses `.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })`
So any help is appreciated.
Here is my simple fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tekh27my/

Comment: this seem to be svg/d3 only question? If so then the canvas tag can be removed to avoid unnecessary "noise"

Comment: Sorry, in the other question it said that it might be done with canvas so I put the tag if someone knows another solution using canvas.

Comment: ah, no problem in that case.

Comment: @K3N provided a canvas solution, but this is also possible using svg with paths. I made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tekh27my/1/) which shows what I mean. Note that this path function still needs some work, but if you align the circles vertically or horizontally you'll see what I mean. The `if (true)` statement would be replaced by your condition for drawing a wedged line.

Comment: @JSBob You should provide this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a variable width polyline in canvas you would have to do one of two things:

- Calculate the new path running along the polyline extruded from center. This has to take into account joins, angles, enclosed points at inner corners, added triangles or arcs at outer corners and so forth (this can be applied to paths for both SVG and canvas).
- Draw the polyline segmented, meaning that for each segment you increase/decrease the thickness joining the segment with "round" mode. For long segments you would also have to interpolate the segment to avoid steep changes.

The latter would be the simplest solution of the two:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    line = [116,34,116,37,116,39,116,49,119,71,126,103,140,141,160,181,190,224,226,263,263,
            293,312,316,363,327,416,328,458,322,491,313,515,295,537,272,557,244,570,
            224,580,208,586,196,591,188,595,182,596,178,598,176,601,174,604,172,605,171],
    line2 = [],          // the interpolated segments
    maxSubSeg = 16,      // number of sub-segements
    minThick = 2,        // taper thickness
    maxThick = 16;

// interpolate the line to create more segments
for(var i = 0; i < line.length - 2; i += 2) {
  var x1 = line[i],      // get line positions
      y1 = line[i+1],
      x2 = line[i+2],
      y2 = line[i+3];
  
  for(var j = 0; j < maxSubSeg; j++) {
    line2.push(
      x1 + (x2-x1) * (j/maxSubSeg),   // interpolate X
      y1 + (y2-y1) * (j/maxSubSeg)    // interpolate Y
    )
  }
}

// render new line
ctx.lineCap = "round";

for(var i = 0; i < line2.length - 2; i += 2) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(line2[i], line2[i+1]);
  ctx.lineTo(line2[i+2], line2[i+3]);
  ctx.lineWidth = minThick + maxThick * (i/line2.length);  // use length as t [0,1]
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=640 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonders how to do this. Here's my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tekh27my/2/

I've calculated the M and L attributes of the path in the tick function:

```
 d3.selectAll(".link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {

                var radius = 10;

                    if(d.target.x > d.source.x && d.target.y < d.source.y){
                        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + " L" + (d.target.x - radius) + "," + (d.target.y - radius) + " L" + (d.target.x + radius) + "," + (d.target.y + radius) + " L" + d.source.x + ", " + d.source.y;
                    }else if(d.target.x < d.source.x && d.target.y > d.source.y){
                        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + " L" + (d.target.x + radius) + "," + (d.target.y + radius) + " L" + (d.target.x - radius) + "," + (d.target.y - radius) + " L" + d.source.x + ", " + d.source.y;
                    }else{
                        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + " L" + (d.target.x - radius) + "," + (d.target.y + radius) + " L" + (d.target.x + radius) + "," + (d.target.y - radius) + " L" + d.source.x + ", " + d.source.y;}
           });
```